# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application to work both offline and online mode

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a POS system using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. I want it to work offline in case there is no internet connectivity.

How can we make an ASP.NET Core MVC app work with a local and remote database?

Comment: Adding different Connection Strings does not solve my problem. I want my application to work as a PWA application. It should be able to work the same way in both offline and online modes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs description, I think the following scheme will be more suitable for you.

#### The first situation:

*1. You need to have one physical server (used to deploy the website and install the database), or two, depending on your performance requirements.*

*2. If you have an independent public network IP, it is best. If you don't, you need to use an intranet penetration tool, such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). When users have a network, they can access the public network.*

If the above two conditions are met, when the Internet gateway service is disconnected, users in your intranet can still access the website and can work normally. However, if you leave the intranet, such as when you return home, you will not be able to access it. At this time, it is equivalent to offline.

When the public network environment of the intranet is restored, it can be accessed from the public network again.

#### The second situation:

If you are using a cloud server, this situation does not exist. I don't think it makes sense to use offline and remote databases. When it is stored in the local database when offline, there will always be data out of sync.